# Find the sum upto $n$ terms: $\frac{1/2}{a^2}+\frac{1/4}{4a^2}+\frac{1/8}{9a^2}+\frac{1/16}{16a^2}+\frac{1/32}{25a^2}+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, contest-math

> Find the sum upto $n$ terms: $\frac{1/2}{a^2}+\frac{1/4}{4a^2}+\frac{1/8}{9a^2}+\frac{1/16}{16a^2}+\frac{1/32}{25a^2}+...$

**My Attempt:**

$$\frac1{a^2}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\frac1{2^r}}{r^2}$$

I was hoping to write it in terms of some difference so that I could get telescoping. But not able to do so.

I tried multiplying and dividing by $2$, but in vain.

In the given series, I tried multiplying the coefficients but in vain.

I was hoping to get some some AP or GP but not happening.

I tried writing $2^{-r}$ to see if it could fit somehow with $r^2$ but not able to do so.

Comment: HINT: $${x^r\over r^2}=\int_0^x {1\over t}\int_0^t s^{r-1} \, ds \, dt$$

Answer (score 3):

First consider the series
\begin{align}
f(t) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{t^k}{k^2} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k^2} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k^2} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k^2} - t^{n+1} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{(k+n+1)^2} \\
f(t) &= \text{Li}_{2}(t) - t^{n+1} \, \phi(t, 2, n+1),
\end{align}
where $\text{Li}_{2}(x)$ is the dilogarithm function and $\phi(x, a, s)$ is the Hurwitz Lerch function. When $t = 1/2$ the series becomes
\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) &= \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \, \phi\left(\frac{1}{2}, 2, n+1\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, (\zeta(2) - \ln^{2}(2)) - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \, \phi\left(\frac{1}{2}, 2, n+1\right).
\end{align}
In this form the Hurwitz Lerch function should keep the form
$$ \phi\left(\frac{1}{2}, 2, n+1\right) = -a_{n} + b_{n} \, \zeta(2) - c_{n} \, \ln^{2}(2), $$
where $a_{n}, b_{n}, c_{n}$ are constants but depend on $n$, and suggests that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{k} \, k^2} = \frac{a_{n}}{2^{n+1}} + \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{b_{n}}{2^{n+1}}\right) \, \zeta(2) - \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{c_{n}}{2^{n+1}}\right) \, \ln^{2}(2). $$

With some "work" it can be shown that $b_{n} = c_{n} = 2^{n}$ which reduces the series to
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^k \, k^2} = \frac{a_{n}}{2^{n+1}}. $$
This result seems to be inefficient, but does show that there are known functions that will lead to the proper result. It appears that this result has taken a circular path and ended up at the beginning. With numbers, which can be generated from the series, one can turn to the trusted source of numbers, namely the [OEIS](https://oeis.org). Taking the numerators $$\{0, 1, 9, 83, 1337, 33497, 5587, 136919, 35054939, 946522553, ...\}_{n\geq0}$$ and denominators
$$ \{1, 2, 16, 144, 2304, 57600, 9600, 235200, 60211200, 1625702400, ...\}_{n \geq 0} $$
then one finds sequences [A242596](https://oeis.org/A242596) and [A242597](https://oeis.org/A242597) which leads to the statement
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^k \, k^2} = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \, \frac{A242596(n)}{A242597(n)}. $$